# How to install drivers from Sony website

Tags: windows-8, drivers, smartphone

How do you install [these Xperia Z2 drivers](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-z2-driver/) from Sony on Windows 8.1? Yes I've done an advance boot and disabled driver signature verification. I manually browse to the folder but it says "Windows could not find driver software for your device" which isn't surprising as there isn't even anything that looks like a driver in the downloaded archive.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The driver is fine. It's an [INF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INF_file). Do you have a USB 2.0 port on your computer you could connect the phone to?

Comment: @Vinayak what makes you say the driver is fine, do you see the screen shot saying the driver couldn't be installed? Yes I have USB 2.0 ports.

Comment: I saw it's fine because I've installed similar drivers on my Windows 8.1 computer. I have a Sony phone as well and the driver they provided for my phone was an INF driver, similar to yours. You can try connecting the phone to the USB 2.0 port and then try [installing the driver](http://www.rm.com/support/technicalarticle.asp?cref=tec6643)

Comment: Found the solution, don't really understand it but it works if you install device drivers by clicking on the option "let me pick from a list of drivers on my computer" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXtbAMarHQw

Comment: @Celeritas - Post the steps with screenshots as an answer.

Comment: Well using this link you can download the latest drivers for Xperia devices http://doomlord.xperia-files.com/download.php?dlid=Rmxhc2h0b29sLWRyaXZlcnMtMS41LTIwMTQwMzE4